# Unable to instantiate activity?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i'm getting this error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.bassammetwally.like/com.example.bassammetwally.like.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
```

when i'm **trying to switch activity in another method** in the 
`mainActivity.class`

The Code i'm trying to run(not going to include libraries);

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    final Intent i = new Intent(this, profile.class);
    ImageButton ButtonOne = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.profile);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final Intent i = new Intent(this, profile.class);
        ImageButton ButtonOne = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.profile);
        ButtonOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                button();
            }
        });

    }

    public void button()
    {
        startActivity(i);
    }


}
```

code before that worked

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final Intent i = new Intent(this, profile.class);
        ImageButton ButtonOne = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.profile);
        ButtonOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick( View v ){
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

}}
```

Questions:

1. What is the meaning of the error?
2. why is this error showing?

Comment: don't you have google??

Answer (score 0):

You're initiating variable `i` twice. When going to function `button()` you are using the one in public scope (above the `onCreate` method), not the one from `onCreate`. Your code should look like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final Intent i = new Intent(this, profile.class);
    ImageButton ButtonOne = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.profile);
    ButtonOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            button(i);
        }
    });

}

public void button(Intent i)
{
    startActivity(i);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
final Intent i ;
ImageButton ButtonOne ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    i =new Intent(MainActivity.this, profile.class);
     ButtonOne  = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.profile);
    ButtonOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            button();
        }
    });

}

public void button()
{
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ImageButton ButtonOne = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.profile);

        ButtonOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, profile.class);
            startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Also Added Profile.java in manifest file**